# Why recognizes 'find' dirs as executables

Tags: command-line-arguments

Does anybody know, why

```
find -executable
```

lists directories? (I know, how to circumvent it by adding

```
-type f
```

;-) but wish I didn't have to

Answer (score 2):

The `-executable` argument tests that the "thing" (file or directory) can be "executed" by the current user. In the case of a directory, that means the user can enter (`cd` into) the directory. In the case of a file, that means the user can execute the file.

So both files and directories can be "executed" in the sense that `find -executable` uses.

Comment: beat me to the answer by 15 secs.